# I think my code is clean but I end up with 0 lines

Tags: python-3.x, list

My code in not working as intended and I have no clue

```
def fun(line):
    list_three = []
    list_more = []
    index = 0
    for item in line:
        if len(item) == 3:
            list_three.append(item)
            index += 1
            return item
        elif len(item) > 3:
            list_more.append(item)
            index += 1
            return "this string has more than three char"
        else:
            index += 1
            return None
```

verbs = ["eat", "look", "dance"]
fun(verbs)

Comment: what is your expected "output"? Try printing the result of `fun()` to see if it's correct, e.g.: `print(fun(verbs))`

Comment: What's the function of your variable, "index", it looks useless

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't have any syntax errors,
but, to begin with, you should call the function with a list-argument.

I have added a few lines, marked #temp, 
which illustrate what happens.

Here, the function looks at the first item, "4444",
goes to the elif command, prints the list list_more
and returns the returnvalue.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
    """
    study.py
    """
    def fun(line):
        list_three = []
        list_more = []
        index = 0
        for item in line:
            if len(item) == 3:
                list_three.append(item)
                print("list_three",list_three)  #temp
                index += 1
                return item
            elif len(item) > 3:
                list_more.append(item)
                print("list_more",list_more)  #temp
                index += 1
                return "this string has more than three char"
            else:
                index += 1
                return None

    print(fun([ "4444", "333", "55555"]))  #temp
```